# Dynamically adjust the height of a table in Vue.js if its rows are smaller than 15

Tags: javascript, css, vue.js, dynamic, height

I am working in Vue.js and trying to dynamically display a table according to its height. I have managed that if the number of rows is greater than 15, the table is displayed in a 'height: 50vh'. The problem is when the number of rows is less than 15.

The component is `<v-card :items="tableItems" :items-per-page="15"/>` and I added `:style="getTableHeight()"`

```
getTableHeight() {
    const tableItemsCount = this.tableItems.length;
    const maxVisibleRows = 15;
    const maxHeight = `50vh`;

      return {'--height': maxHeight};
}
```

And then, in css I added that variable to the height: `height: var(--height);`

I have tried to adjust it manually by means of a conditional if inside the getTableHeight method, as follows:

```
getTableHeight() {
    const tableItemsCount = this.tableItems.length;
    const maxVisibleRows = 15;
    const maxHeight = `50vh`;

    if (tableItemsCount <= maxVisibleRows) {

      const rowHeight = 70; // I would like to adjust it dynamically
      const height = `${tableItemsCount * rowHeight}px`;
      return {'--height': height};

    } else {

      return {'--height': maxHeight};

    }
}
```

Comment: Did you try by giving the `window.innerHeight` ?